# Yukawa exchange model

Tags: particle-physics, strong-force

For my physics class I have to answer the following question.
Why do we need two pion exchange and rho meson exchange , and not just one pion in order to explain the strong interaction.
My thought is that we must explain why the strong force is reppeling at very short distances , attractive at medium distances and it decays with longer distances but I am not quite sure is this is the right answer.
Any ideas?